# How does my ISP knows that I am sharing my internet connection? and how to bypass it?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, network-shares, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I am in a student residence hall.There is one ethernet socket in the room. I can connect my laptop to the cable, but how can I get internet in my iPad? 
It will be good to have internet on both of them, but if not possible I can live with internet only at one of them at a time.

My configurations are as follows:
I am connected to internet via ethernet cable on my MBP laptop. I want to have access to internet wirelessly on my iPad as well. How can I config my MBP (OSX 10.6.8) to act as an "Access Point" ?

I already tried the internet sharing via system preferences. 
I could connect to my shared network on my iPad, but the problem is my ISP does now allow network sharing! On my iPad it shows the following error message:

"We have detected that you are using a router or a device that is performing network connection sharing. Sharing a connection with multiple devices is against out term of use."..."You can use a router on our network, however it must be configures to act as an access point."
Then it mentions that I should turn off DHCP in the router settings.

How does my ISP knows that I am sharing my internet connection? and how to bypass it? Or if not possible, how I use my macbook pro to act just as an access point, (not as router, and DHCP of)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you afford to purchase an access point?  That would be the simplest way to solve the problem.  It seems sharing the connection among devices is fine, you are just not permitting to route (which is what connection sharing the way you have it does)

Comment: well, if I cannot solve it by configuring my macbook, then I have to buy it, thought it will be waste as I am staying a short time here.

With access point, and with DHCP off, I can only have one device connected to internet at a time, right?

Comment: No, an access point extends the layer 2 network into your location - this means that you can use multiple machines where you are, they will just get their IP addresses from the ISP dhcp.  To do this with a macbook pro, you need to bridge the wifi and lan ports together.  Someone else may be able to answer how to do that.

Comment: when you attempt what you and your isp are calling 'network sharing'  do both your devices have an external address?  in which case you're requesting an IP from your ISP twice.  You should have private IPs not external ones. And if you did turn DHCP off you could still use a static IP.  You can share it further from ISP. been a while since I bridged network connections  but sounds like a good idea to try.

Comment: Thanks guys,

From your comments, it seems that the solution is to bridge my Lan port with AirPort. I tried the guide here (replaced xbox with iPad, and swapped ethernet with wifi). But it did not get through :(

Still the same problem. I tried different stuff, either my iPad is not connected, or I get the same error saying that I use router. :(

Comment: Anyone? please?